# MongoPasswordField setPassword + save

Tags: scala, lift

I've started working a little bit with lift+scala+mongorecord but I found a small annoyance :

Usually to easily create a record ( document ) I just do:

```
User.createRecord.loginName("user").firstName("Name").lastName("LastName").save
```

But when I use the MongoPasswordField it is impossible to do it in just one line:

```
val userRecord = User.createRecord.loginName("user").firstName("Name").lastName("LastName")
userRecord.password.setPassword("SomePassword")|
userRecord.save
```

Source code for the filed is at http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.2/framework/scaladocs/lift-persistence/lift-mongodb-record/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/mongodb/record/field/MongoPasswordField.scala.html

Is there any way of doing this in just one line?
or at least can the field code be modified in some way to actually allow doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do this:

```
User.createRecord.loginName("user").firstName("Name").lastName("LastName").password(Password("Some password")).save
```